# Where can I find a list of APDU commands for a DoD CAC

Tags: smartcard, apdu, cac

I am looking for APDU commands to be used for a DoD CAC. I'm trying to pull as much information as I can off the card. So far Google has not been of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link to get more information about the CAC card:

http://www.cac.mil/common-access-card/developer-resources/

In it you will find a standard document titled:

> Interfaces for Personal Identity Verification – Part 2: End-Point PIV
>   Card Application Card Command Interface

Comment: Personally, I think this publicly available information was pretty easy to find.

Comment: The File you speak of does not exist. It is also password protected.

Comment: I copied that title out of the document itself. Download the CDK by following the link, unzip and start browsing through the folders.

Comment: Did you manage to find the document? Or are you still in limbo?

Comment: i did find it. Thanks. I'll look through that